# Ember CLI sends analytics information by default to who?

Tags: ember.js, analytics, ember-cli

This is the .ember-cli file.

```
{
  /**
    Ember CLI sends analytics information by default. The data is completely
    anonymous, but there are times when you might want to disable this behavior.

    Setting `disableAnalytics` to true will prevent any data from being sent.
  */
  "disableAnalytics": false
}
```

Who does Ember CLI send analytics to by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it amazing that we can track anything in our tools when it has open sources? Let's track together.

**The question:** what is it in general?

**The answer:** the analytic tool is [leek](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/2bce175ce188ae0f47a55fa23d6affe2d768ddfb/lib/cli/index.js#L87), which is made for [GA tracking](https://github.com/twokul/leek). Obviously it requires a tracking code, so we can see [where it is populated](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/2bce175ce188ae0f47a55fa23d6affe2d768ddfb/lib/cli/index.js#L21). The very code is [here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/package.json#L143).

---

**The question:** what it tracks?

**The answer:** I don't know every tracking library, but we can find something useful in a repo. There are 3 tracking commands - `trackEvent`, `trackError`, and `track`. Later I found one more - `trackTiming`.

Let's use native Github search in order to know, how it is used in ember-cli project. Nothing for `.trackEvent`; the only positive relevant for `.trackError` - [sending an error message](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/2bce175ce188ae0f47a55fa23d6affe2d768ddfb/lib/models/watcher.js#L33). But a general `.track` is used more frequent - [I had to use a limiting parameter in the search](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.track%20path%3Alib&type=Code). So the final list of events - addition/changing of file, building/rebuilding time, live reloading event, and something [not obvious here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/2bce175ce188ae0f47a55fa23d6affe2d768ddfb/lib/models/command.js#L198).

---

**The question:** I just asked who is a recipient, why can't you answer directly?

**The answer**: now we know, that the main player here is leek, so let's go through it. The library is very small, hence we could even bruteforce it. The main file has the only important method, where we can easily see the [source of url](https://github.com/twokul/leek/blob/master/lib/leek.js#L64). The module is in the same folder, and unfortunately our journey ends [here](https://github.com/twokul/leek/blob/master/lib/provider.js#L117).

Comment: Thanks you very much Dmitry!

Answer (score 0):

[The ember and ember-cli core teams](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/c9320aeb9fb521887bd8fec8f722bef0608c9fe5/docs/analytics.md#who-has-access)

The linked readme also details what is tracked and why.