# What is connecting Google behind the scene in Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember is running, in the console, such errors sometimes show up.

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.221.164:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '216.58.221.164',
  port: 443 }
```

The IP is Google. I check web app network in browser console. Nothing there. What else can I do to find out what is trying to connect google. I am not using Material Design which I knew maybe using google fonts.

But I do have ember-bootstrap-4. Here is a full list of my packages.json and bower.json. Please help.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-bootstrap-4": "0.1.2",
    "ember-cli": "2.8.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.5.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.8.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.1"
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.8.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1",
    "tether": "^1.3.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: `.ember-cli` there is `disableAnalytics` configuration make it `true`. this will stop sending analytics information..i am not sure is this related to your issue. may be give it try

Comment: have a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683636/ember-cli-sends-analytics-information-by-default-to-who).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is offline or dead slow in speed, there is a chance for you to get this error. Ember-cli sends error messages to google analytics. so to stop this set `disableAnalytics` to true in `.ember-cli` configuration file. by default this would be false.